# Using Azure as infrastructure as a service, configuring HTTPS endpoints / load balancer

Tags: https, azure, infrastructure, endpoint

I am quiete now to the topic of routing traffic, since it's done by our hosting provider so far.

I would like to setup some Virtual machines and configure HTTPS and Loadbalancing on Azure.
I do pick the Virtual machines, and not website as a service. So in general Infrastructure only.

How can I do the endpoint configuration using a VM on azure?
When I read documents like this:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/
it doesn't help me much :)

is there any dummy explanation? Can I add my own ssl cert easily to my azure vm? Or is that only possible if I select a website instead of VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the VM, you have full control. So adding the certificate and configuring any internal services (such as IIS) would be done as you would normally.

As far as creating the load balanced endpoints... there's a doc linked the one above that provides details steps [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internet-getstarted/).

From there it links to another that you'll want to run through: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn469417.aspx

In short, there's two steps when creating load balanced VMs: first place them into the same "set", then define the load balanced endpoints. These steps can be done via powershell, or the "classic" management portal.

Comment: thank you sir, that was more or less my assumption. But what about availability of my loadbalancer, do I have to create a pair of LoadBalancing VM's in order to prevent a downtime?

Comment: LB functionality (it also does NAT) is provided by Azure. If you check the Azure SLAs on compute, its all based on connectivity to a load balanced set of VMs in an availability set. So unless you do, the SLAs do not apply.